# How can I deal with such C++ strange exception in file reading?

Tags: c++, cmake, file-read

## Origin

I was trying to build a graph data structure and I want to use a .txt file to initialize the graph. The first time it runs successfully. But after I added another `DAG.txt` file, exception happened.

### Information

- OS: Windows 10
- Develop Environment: VS Code with Git, CMake and MinGW64.

The file organization:

```
D:.
├───.vscode
├───build
│   ├───.cmake
│   │   └───api
│   │       └───v1
│   │           ├───query
│   │           │   └───client-vscode
│   │           └───reply
│   ├───bin(.dll and .exe file)
│   ├───CMakeFiles
│   │   ├───3.19.2
│   │   │   ├───CompilerIdC
│   │   │   │   └───tmp
│   │   │   └───CompilerIdCXX
│   │   │       └───tmp
│   │   ├───CMakeTmp
│   │   ├───Graph_Algorithm.dir
│   │   │   └───src
│   │   └───Main.dir
│   └───Testing
│       ├───20210421-1414
│       └───Temporary
├───include(.hpp file)
├───rsrc(Including .txt file)
└───src
(Main.cpp, CMakeLists.txt etc)
```

## Details

`UGraph` is a class template. I use a `char` array to initialize the vertex vector `Vertex` and a `Edge.txt` to initialize the adjacency matrix `Edge`. The `Edge.txt` was written in this format:

```
0 1 1
0 1 2
0 2 3
2 1 3

1 2 1
4 1 1
```

Vertex1-Weight-Vertex2.

The constructor:

```cpp
template<typename Tp>
UGraph<Tp>::UGraph(const Tp arr[], size_t num, std::ifstream& edge, Mode mode) : Vertex(arr, arr + num), size(num)
{
    // Allocate memory
    Edge = new double*[MAX];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        Edge[i] = new double[10];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < MAX; j++){
            if(i == j)
                Edge[i][j] = 0;
            else
                Edge[i][j] = Infinity;
        }
    }

    // TODO Get edge data and connect the vertecies
    if (!edge || edge.eof()){
        throw "Initial file is invalid.";
    }
 
    while(!edge.eof()){
        double weight;
        size_t i, j;// Vertecies indecies
        edge >> i;
        edge >> weight;
        edge >> j;

        // Watch
        cout << i << ' ' << weight << ' ' << j << endl;

        if (i > size - 1 || j > size - 1) { throw "Index overflow at constructor."; }
        switch (mode)
        {
        case Mode::UN_DIRECTED:
            Edge[j][i] = weight;
        case Mode::DIRECTED:
            Edge[i][j] = weight;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    edge.close();

    // //Test
    // for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
    //     for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++){
    //         if(Edge[i][j] != Infinity){
    //             cout << Edge[i][j] << ' ';
    //         }else{
    //             cout << "INF" << ' ';
    //         }
    //     }
    //     cout << endl;
    // }
    
}
```

The `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)
project(Graph_Algorithm)

# Collect file
aux_source_directory(./src SRC)
include_directories(./include)

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# Generate lib
add_library(Graph_Algorithm SHARED ${SRC} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/UGraph.hpp)

# Header file
target_include_directories(Graph_Algorithm
PUBLIC 
./include)

# Compile
add_executable(Main main.cpp)

# Link
target_link_libraries(Main Graph_Algorithm)
```

The Main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "UGraph.hpp"

int main(){
    try{
        std::ifstream file("./../../rsrc/DAG.txt");
        char s[]{"ABCDEFGHIJKMLNOPQRSTU"};
        UGraph<char> ug(s, 14, file, UGraph<char>::Mode::DIRECTED);
        std::vector<size_t> vec;
        ug.BreadthFirstTraverse(0);
        // ug.DepthFirstTraverse();
        ug.Prim();
        cout << endl;
        ug.Kruskal();
        ug.Dijstra(3, vec);
        
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e){
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    catch(const char* msg){
        std::cerr << "ErrorFound: " << msg << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The `class UGraph`:

```cpp
const double Infinity{99999.9};

template<typename Tp>
class UGraph
{
private:
    std::vector<Tp> Vertex;
    // Adjacent Matrix, Row is out, Colum is in.
    double ** Edge;
    size_t size;

public:
    static const unsigned int MAX{10};
    enum class Mode { DIRECTED, UN_DIRECTED };

    UGraph();
    UGraph(const Tp arr[], size_t num, std::ifstream& edge, Mode mode = Mode::UN_DIRECTED);
    ~UGraph();
    double*& operator[](size_t i) { 
        if (i > size - 1){
            throw "Index Overflow at [] operator.";
        }
        return Edge[i]; 
    }
    auto BreadthFirstTraverse(size_t root);
    void DepthFirstTraverse();
    void DFS(size_t root, std::vector<bool>& Visited);
    void Prim();
    void Kruskal();
    void Dijstra(size_t v1, std::vector<size_t>& shortestWay);
    // void Floyd();
};
```

## Exceptions

If using CMake Launch, it reads some of lines then aborts, shows nothing;

if using cmd or powershell launch, it shows "Initial file is invaild.";

if using gdb, it shows the same massage as powershell.

- This program once worked smoothly. The exceptions happened when another initial file was used.

> All the message are contained in exception objects (Most of them are strings), which will be catched by `int main()` them be showed in stderr.

Comment: What is the value of `MAX`?  You are doing `Edge[i] = new double[10];` and then immediately running a loop where you assign `MAX` elements to that array of 10 elements.

Comment: "it shows 'initial file is invalid'" -- WHO shows that?  Your code doesn't print that any where here.

Comment: @TimRoberts Actually it does. After checking if the `ifstream` is ok.

Comment: `while (!edge.eof()) { ... }` is an issue. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons). As for cmd/powershell it most likely doesn't find the file.

Comment: My bad, you're right.  The implication, then, is that the file is no longer located at the same relative location in all your example.

Comment: @paddy The second parameter `size_t num` of the constructor is the value of `MAX` ( I use `const size_t UGraph::size` replace `MAX` macro).

Comment: @TimRoberts The most weird thing is that the another file that located in the same folder can work successfully...